# Can you replicate a Trimpot with a 555 timer?

Tags: timer, potentiometer, variable

I'm currently a senior ME major and just entered the EE world to complete project so I'm a little lost.

I am building a circuit powered by an Arduino Mega Chip. The circuit is to control electromagnetic coils and subsequent magnets via a voltage follower circuit.

The circuit currently uses a trimpot to vary the +/- voltage. I would like to automate this by potentially using a 555 timer to vary between positive and negative voltages at the output. From what I'm reading, a 555 timer outputs square waves; from 0v to +v not -v to +v.

Is there any way to power my circuit using a 555 timer, or is there a more efficient way to go about this I may have missed?

[image: coil drive pic]

Comment: How does the arduino factor into this? Can't you use it to do what you want in software?

Comment: The Arduino will be used to supply power to the board and components. I thought it might be best to use Arduino to supply power in case I need to make other separate configurations to the system down the line. In this case though, Arduino is just supplying power. The Arduino only supplies +V. Right now I have it supplying a charge pump to convert to -V for the trimpot. I would like to use the ard to power the 555 and thus, output +/-. I hope that makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you’re asking for is a means to use a pulse-width-modulated, or PWM signal to control your drivers. The 555 can do that, but you still have control the 555 to set the duty cycle. Which kind of defeats the purpose of it being a ‘replacement’ for a trim pot.

The Arduino supports PWM and could do this by itself, no 555 is necessary. You will need to translate the ATMega’s logic-level outputs to those for the coil drives. A good way to do this is to use a *half-bridge driver* IC which has buffers and voltage translation built in.

Can you drive both ends of your coils? If so, then you can use a *full H bridge* driver and a single-ended power supply. Such a thing is available as an Arduino shield, like this one: https://store.arduino.cc/products/arduino-motor-shield-rev3

Comment: You were speaking Latin to me until I did some more research on what you were suggesting. It makes complete sense. Thanks so much. You're suggesting I can control an H-bridge via Arduino's PWM. Based on my inputs to the H-Bridge, it will feed an alternating current to my inverting input at the follower circuit. Did I get that correct?

Comment: It depends on the approach you use for the PWM. It can be integrated to make a DC voltage output, or you can drive the coils with PWM chop directly to get a propionate control. Check the h-bridge driver datasheet for details.

Comment: probablty just a low-pass filter and an op-amp to do the level conversion, no need for an additional driver to what they already have.

Comment: The L298 can only do a PWM chop. It doesn’t accept analog levels. You regulate current using a sense resistor and feeding that back to the host so it can modify the PWM chop as needed.

Comment: I should emphasize that servo drivers usually work on current, not voltage. In your diagram you would add a current sense somewhere and feed that back to your driver. With the Arduino shield L298 IC, although it isn’t linear, you feed it with PWM chop and sense the average current to close the loop. The Arduino project with the shield should have code for all that.

Comment: You then need to decide on the control loop design - this is where ME meets EE…

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. Much appreciated!